# Table numbers restart using \ContinuedFloat

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, subfloats

Okay, I am really new at LaTeX so I may be screwing up terribly, but here's my problem.  I'm writing a paper with several tables, one of which is in three parts, so I'm using `\ContinuedFloat` from the `caption` package to try to get correct captions.

What I want is the first table to be `Table 1`, then to have `Table 2a, 2b, 2c`.  Instead, I get `Table 1` and then `Table 1a`, `Table 1b`, `Table 1c`.  Here's what I have (I apologize if it isn't enough, I'm not quite sure what you need!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{cont}{#1˜#2\alph{ContinuedFloat}}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelformat=cont}
\usepackage[]{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{plachit.jpg}
\caption{}
\label{plachit}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{kisel1.jpg}}
\caption{Tier 1}
\label{kisel1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{kisel2.jpg}}
\caption{Tier 2}
\label{kisel2}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{kisel3.jpg}}
\caption{Tier 3}
\label{kisel3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I wasn't using `subfloat` at first, but from looking around trying to find an answer, it seemed like other people were.  Not exactly sure if it's necessary.

Comment: At the moment you have both `(a)` and `Table 1a`, so there seems to be `2` captions- do you want to keep this? If not then there'll probably be an option using the `subcaption` package, a sibling of the `caption` package

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by having 2 captions-- what causes that?  I tried using the subcaption package, by following the directions here [link](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/publishing/latex_captions), but now it is throwing this error:  [5] [6] (c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlcmr.fd) [7]
<plachit.jpg, id=32, 419.31656pt x 156.585pt> <use plachit.jpg>
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.159  \includegraphics
                       {kisel1.jpg}
?  Also, I'm not sure how to make a post on this to show the new code.

Comment: The cause is `\subfloat[<caption goes here>]{\includegraphics{kise13.jpg}}` and `\caption{}`. You can click on the `edit` button to update your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that using the `\ContinuedFloat` method of the `caption` package may constitute a bit of abuse of that method. To my understanding, the `ContinuedFloat` method is intended to be used in cases where a single "float" (such as a figure or table) doesn't fit on one page and the need arises to link the two (or more) separate parts using some recognizable terminology. In your case, in contrast, I can't discern what is supposed to link Table 1 to Table 2 (which happens to come in three parts). If your Table 2 ends up being too large to fit on a single page, you may want to consider limiting the use of `\ContinuedFloat` instructions to just that table.

Since you appear to have two main tables ("floats", in LaTeX parlance), one of which has three components (or "tiers", as you call them), you may want to use the `subcaption` package and its `subtable` environment. Note that it's possible to assign captions to (and hence cross-reference) the sub-tables individually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{A single-tiered table}
\centering
\includegraphics{plachit.jpg}
\label{plachit}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{A table with three tiers}
\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{kisel1.jpg}
\caption{Tier 1} \label{kisel1}
\end{subtable}

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{kisel2.jpg}
\caption{Tier 2}
\label{kisel2}
\end{subtable}

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{kisel3.jpg}
\caption{Tier 3}
\label{kisel3}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  You've saved me hours of frustration. :)